# When to use one-hot encoding and when to use dummy variable?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, cluster-analysis

I have short question here. I want to know when and what situation to use one-hot encoding and when should use dummy variable.

I am planning to do clustering analysis with categorical and numerical variables. I read in one forum that I can try encode the categorical variables using one-hot encoding. But I wonder what makes it different with dummy variable.

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion its the same thing. One-hot encoded variables are dummy variables are [same](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/5bhmvz/whats_the_difference_between_one_hot_encoding_and/).

Comment: I would like to know as well what the difference betwee one-hot encoding and dummy variables are?  Is it just a terminology thing where one-hot encoding is used in ML while dummy variables are used in statistics?  (Kinda like features vs. predictor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most clustering algorithms will be distance based.

Any such encoding is a hack to make categoricial data look as if it were numeric, but this only postpones the resulting problems: how to normalize, weight, decorrelate, and combine features.

For most clustering algorithms, it makes an enormous difference whether you dummy encode as 0,1 or as 0,100000 or as 0,0.000001. So which one should you use? There is no objective mathematical answer to this, and it causes severe problems.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that dummy encoding typically removes one of the columns. E.g. a variable with 3 levels will get 2 dummy variables and 3 one-hot-encoded variables. This is to ensure that you have no multicollinearity. One-hot-encoding is sometimes also called full dummy encoding